# Как установить шрифты C#?

Tags: c#, .net, шрифты

Пробую решение из [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21986744/12888024), там используется утилита [FontReg](http://code.kliu.org/misc/fontreg/) и следующий код:

```
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "Path\to\FontReg.exe",
            Arguments = "/copy",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

        };

   Process.Start(info);
```

**Моя программа запускается от имени администратора.** В директории с утилитой находятся нужные шрифты, после запуска ничего не происходит — шрифты не добавляются в папку `C:/Windows/Fonts` и не устанавливаются.

В документации утилиты написано, что она устанавливает все шрифты, которые находятся в текущей директории. Пробую запустить её вручную — тоже не устанавливается.

А другой предложенный код:

```
Process.Start("Path\to\file.ttf")
```

Просто запускает шрифт и нужно самому нажать "*Установить*", это уже не программная установка.

Comment: вы пробовали другие ответы из того вопроса?

Comment: насколько я знаю, достаточно просто скопировать шрифт в папку шрифтов виндовс, что бы шрифт установился, попробуйте сделать тоже самое только на C#

Comment: @KuzCode недостаточно. Копирование с автоматической установкой - это фишка проводника винды explorer.exe, который интегрирован с приложением fonts, но идея покопать в этом направлении хорошая.

Comment: @KuzCode _Кроме того, в документации MSDN говорится, что шрифт будет удален после перезагрузки компьютера, если шрифт не будет добавлен в реестр._

Comment: @aepot ещё нет, они более объёмные и сложные, FontReg по описанию идеально подходит, я думала я что-то делаю не так, из-за чего он не работает...

Comment: https://brutaldev.com/post/installing-and-removing-fonts-using-c#:~:text=Add%20your%20font%20file%20(the,That's%20it!